# Unable to resolve import statements in google protobuf file using maven protobuf-maven-plugin plugin while generating the java classes

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, protocol-buffers

The file which contains the import statements.

```
import "goproto/common/date.proto";
import "goproto/common/timestamp.proto";
import "goproto/common/custom_options.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.kafka.proto";

message KafkaInfoLogProto {
    int32 pid = 1;
    com.types.Timestamp event_time = 2;
    string tid = 3;
    string device_id = 4;
    string email = 5;
    string city_id = 6;
    com.types.Date check_in = 7;
    com.types.Date check_out = 8;
}
```

The import proto files are present in another  directory named common and for example let me describe one of the proto files which is imported.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.types;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_outer_classname = "DateProto";
option java_package = "com.types";

message Date {
    int32 year = 1;
    int32 month = 2;
    int32 day = 3;
}
```

My pom file looks like :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the plugin used is :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.6.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.19.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                <attachProtoSources>true</attachProtoSources>
                <includeDependenciesInDescriptorSet>true</includeDependenciesInDescriptorSet>
                <protoSourceRoot>../goproto/</protoSourceRoot>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The error which I get.

```
[ERROR] /goproto/aug/kafka_info_log.proto [0:0]: goproto/common/date.proto: File not found.
goproto/common/timestamp.proto: File not found.
kafka_info_log.proto: Import "goproto/common/date.proto" was not found or had errors.
kafka_info_log.proto: Import "goproto/common/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
kafka_info_log.proto:16:5: "com.types.Timestamp" is not defined.
kafka_info_log.proto:21:5: "com.types.Date" is not defined.
kafka_info_log.proto:22:5: "com.types.Date" is not defined.
```

I have already searched the web about this but could not find any solution. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely having a mismatch between at least two of the following:

- protobuf package as specified in the `import` statement
- `package` statement in the protobuf files that are imported
- directory structure for the imported files

Let's take a look at your `Date` message: it is declared in package `com.types`.

Therefore for everything to work, you need, for example, to do the following:

1. move `date.proto` to directory `goproto/common/com/types`
2. declare import in `KafkaInfoLogProto` as:
   `import "com/types/date.proto";`
3. change setting in the `pom.xml` to:
   `<protoSourceRoot>../goproto/common</protoSourceRoot>`

Alternatively:

1. move `date.proto` to directory `goproto/common/com/types`
2. declare import in `KafkaInfoLogProto` as:
   `import "common/com/types/date.proto";`
3. leave the POM as is

This is how protobuf compiler resolves imports. If you are using packages, the relative path under the protobuf source root should match the declared `package`.